# Multiple previous page

Tags: asp.net, cross-page-posting

is it possible to add more than one previous page tag like

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Default3.aspx" %>
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Default3.aspx" %>
```

***Default3.aspx:***

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdexample" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False"  onrowcommand="grdexample_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                **<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" Text="Edit" PostBackUrl="~/Default4.aspx" />**
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="ActMasNm" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ActMasId" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnso" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ActMasId") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

***Default3.cs:***

```
public string id { get; set; }
protected void grdexample_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvrw = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent;<br>
    int rwIndex = gvrw.RowIndex;<br>
    HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField)gvrw.FindControl("hdnso");<br>
    id = hdn.Value;   
}
```

***Default4.aspx:***

```
< PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Default3.aspx" >
```

***Default4.cs***

```
TextBox1.Text = this.PreviousPage.id;
```

Above code is working fine, my problem is, if call this page `Default4.apsx` from `Default1.aspx` how can i fetch id?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use

```
<%@ PreviousPageType TypeName
```

instead of

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath=
```

see it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228169%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**EDIT :**
Chek this [URL](http://www.developerscode.com/2011/03/cross-page-posting-of-form-contents-for.html) for more Details on accessing types..

Comment: hi Mayank, In this case i have to retrive data like PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1")?